# How to add files for missing platforms to Docker image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, dockerfile

Relatively new to Docker and trying to get dev environment tests running in the container. 880 are passing but 3 fail. Here is summary of errors for each:

1. Command Error: qemu-i386: Could not open '/lib/ld-linux.so.2': No such file or directory
2. Command Error: qemu-i386: Could not open '/lib/ld-linux.so.2': No such file or directory
3. qemu-x86_64: Could not open '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2': No such file or directory

I'm running on macOS and when I inspect the image:

```
$ docker image inspect 533f37321266 | grep -A3 Arch
        "Architecture": "arm64",
        "Variant": "v8",
        "Os": "linux",
```

You can see this is build for `linux/arm64`. When I specify the platform in my Dockerfile `FROM --platform=linux/amd64 ruby:3.1.3` then I get a warning in Docker Desktop that the container isn't optimized for my machine and performance will take a hit BUT tests #1 & #2 pass!!  However #3 still does not.

Is it possible to embed those other files that it can't find during the build process? Maybe build for `linux/arm64`, `linux/amd`, AND `linux/amd64` in this image? And, if so, how?  Or is there something else I'm screwing up here?